# How to create mutliple tasks asyncio and get returns values

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm beggining with asyncio and I'm struggling awaiting multiple return values from differents functions.

I want to do something like thread but using asyncio since I'm using async librairies from Azure.

I need to launch in my Thread class some function and I want to launch them in conccurency and await for their results and see if the results are good (I'm in a django test).

Here my current code:

```
class DeviceThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, test_case, device_id, module_id, cert_prim, cert_sec):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.test_case = test_case
        self.device_id = device_id
        self.module_id = module_id
        self.cert_prim = cert_prim
        self.cert_sec = cert_sec


    async def get_twin(self, device):
        try:
            # 0 - Get the twin for the device
            twin = await device.get_twin()
            info(twin)
            return twin['desired']['test'] == "test1device"
        except Exception as e:
            info(format_exc())
            return False


    async def receive_message_cloud(self, device):
        try:
            # 1- Waiting for the first message from the server (Blocking call)
            message = await device.receive_message_cloud()
            return message.data.decode() == "testmessage1"
        except Exception as e:
            info(format_exc())
            return False


    async def send_message_cloud(self, device):
        try:
            # 2 -Sending a message to the backend
            await device.send_message_cloud("testmessage1")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            info(format_exc())
            return False


    async def receive_direct_call_and_respond(self, device):
        try:
            # 3 - Receiving a direct call method from the backend
            method_request = await device.receive_method_request()
            # 4 - Sending result of direct call
            payload = {"test": "testok"}
            status = 200
            await device.send_method_response(method_request, status, payload)
            return (method_request.name == "testmethod1") and (method_request.payload == "testpayload1")
        except Exception as e:
            info(format_exc())
            return False


    async def update_twin_properties(self, device):
        try:
            # 5 - Updating twin properties
            new_properties = {'test', 'test2device'}
            device.patch_twin_reported_properties(new_properties)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            info(format_exc())
            return False


    async def perform(self, device):
        # Creating the tasks that will execute in parrallel
        twin_get_res = asyncio.create_task(self.get_twin(device))
        rec_mess_cloud = asyncio.create_task(self.receive_message_cloud(device))
        send_mess_cloud = asyncio.create_task(self.send_message_cloud(device))
        rec_dir_call = asyncio.create_task(self.receive_direct_call_and_respond(device))
        up_twin_prop = asyncio.create_task(self.update_twin_properties(device))
        # Verify the execution of the routine when done
        self.test_case.assertTrue(await twin_get_res)
        self.test_case.assertTrue(await rec_mess_cloud)
        self.test_case.assertTrue(await send_mess_cloud)
        self.test_case.assertTrue(await rec_dir_call)
        self.test_case.assertTrue(await up_twin_prop)


    def run(self):
        try:
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            # Getting writing the cert content to disk
            open("cert.pem", "w").write(self.cert_prim)
            # Creating a device
            device = IOTHubDevice()
            device.authenticate_device(self.device_id, "cert.pem")
            # Removing cert previously created
            remove("cert.pem")
            asyncio.run(self.perform(device))
        except Exception as e:
            info(format_exc())
            self.test_case.assertFalse(True)
```

As you've seen I'm in a thread and I want to verify some function of Azure IOTHub.

But I get this error :

RuntimeError: Task got Future  attached to a different loop

So my question is : how can I get all these tasks running in the loop and get their individual results ?

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: A small tip, you can use `super().__init__()` in place of `threading.Thread.__init__(self)`.

Comment: idk if this really applies, but I think using `await` on an object from another thread can cause a problem. This reference says to use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(callback, *args)` instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading

Comment: idk if this really applies, but I think using `await` on an object from another thread can cause a problem. This reference says to use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(callback, *args)` instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading